# How to write to_string function?

Tags: c++, string

I'm on cygwin, so I can't use `std::to_string`, it's a famous bug. I tried this:

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
std::string to_string(const T& val)
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream  << val;
    return stream.str(); //invalid use of incomplete type
}


int main(){  }
```

But compiler gave me an error. How can I fix that?

Comment: You should include <sstream>

Comment: what error, add it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to include `sstream`.
Add the line

```
#include <sstream>
```